# How to add more RAID 1 storage on Server after the fact?

Tags: raid1

I have set up a Lenovo TS440 Server (LSI 9240-8i, MegaRaid)) with Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials and (2) RAID 1 mirror arrays.  After noticing that the DATA array (2TB) is actually quite small after Windows Server has been BACKING UP all the client PCs to this DATA 2TB drive, I need more space.

The OS is set up as RAID 1 (2x250GB SSDs)(2 bays).
The DATA is set up as RAID 1 (2x2TB platters)(2 bays).

The Server has 8 BAYS.  4 used now.  4 left.

I want to add 4 more drives for 2 more arrays in RAID 1 mirror.

Is it possible to ADD these after the fact of setting it up initially as described above without destroying the already setup arrays?

As something to think about, can I use (2) of the bays to add a hotswap for each array after the fact also?  Or does NEW RAID ARRAYS need to be started over from scratch?

Thank you for the help.

UPDATE:

From this screenshot, I take it the LSI MegaRaid allows a "Add Configuration" so I can add more drives to the 4 empty bays left on the server?  Do I really have to start over?  Or can I just add 4 more drives (2 more arrays of 2TB (4 drives total for added array... 8 grand total).

[image]

Comment: Maybe be better to spend an evening at work and rebuild array to another type, unless you have some high end raid controller than just convert raid 1 to say 5. And since 2TB is not enough after how long, you'll want your raid to have at least 6TB usable (if not higher) to account for the next year or two. And delete old backups after expiration date.

Comment: No raid 5.  Thats nothing but trouble and raid card no good for it.  Just fine for raid 1.  The question is can I "add" another array after already setting up 2 of them?  Maybe via megaraid bios?

Comment: Yeah raid 5 is no good when you have [raid 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_10_.28RAID_1.2B0.29). If raid controller cant expand array, then hook a drive internal to sata for faster transfer, copy it over one night, next night rebuild array and copy back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time going through EVERY feature in MegaBios with a "little" help from the manual and YES, I can "easily" "add" 4 more drives to my 8 bay system WITHOUT starting over or destroying my initial arrays.  Can even change RAID types.  Very simple. Thanks for the great help all.  :\